# cant read values from a file with new lines

Tags: c

code doesnt accept values from file since when i print some garbage pops up
the file is a textfile with a letter representing a status, and theres a number. there are 5 sets of these , each on new line the letter and the number is seperated with a space, i need to get the numbers in one array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct {
    char status;
    int number;
} information;

int main() {
    int array[5] = {0};
    int i;
    FILE *pointer = fopen("transaction22.txt", "r");
    information information1;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fread(&information1, sizeof(information1), 1, pointer);
        array[i] = information1.number;
        printf("%d", information1.number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read up on fscanf and related functions, what you're doing is completely inappropriate for a text file.

Comment: I guess those numbers are in text form, so why are you tryinng to read them in binary representation ?

Comment: There is such a thing called "Full Stop". It's used as a equivalent to the C-"string" `0`-terminator, but for sentences in most modern languages, to mark the end of a sentence. It is very helpful for humans to parse written text like also SO-questions!

Comment: You might like to gxxgle for "How to read text file using C".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fscanf` instead of `fread` as:

`fscanf(pointer, "%s %d", info1.status, &info1.number);`

where `status` will be defined as `char status[2];` inside `struct information`.

`fread` is used for reading raw bytes (blocks of data) from a file.
Now, you are using a text file and trying to read `sizeof(info)` amount of data which is 5 bytes of data (assuming 32-bit `int`), therefore what you get after first `fread` is:

`info1.status` (1 byte)                         `info1.number` (4 bytes)

Byte 1                                SPACE + number + NEWLINE + [One more byte]
read by `fread`                                (next four bytes read by `fread`)

Thus `info1.number` is storing a garbage value.

Also the successive `fread` call starts reading after the data read by previous `fread`.

Comment: @user3051896 : If u are satisfied with my answer, then please accept it (by clicking the checkmark below upvote/downvote sign).

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a `character` array like `c[5]`. and replace this is with `struct`. variable in fread ..like in for loop

```
fread(c,sizeof(c),1,pointer)
```

than use

```
print("%s\n",c);
```

Comment: That only works if all 'numbers' have the same -- known -- number of digits. I'd well steer away from `fread` for this, there are lots and lots of better alternatives.

Comment: @Jongware if increase the array size like c[30] . further if we use 
memset(&c,'\0',sizeof(c)).
would it still be a problem. I don't think there will be a problem

Comment: That still assumes the number of digits and whitespace is always the same. With *any* other approach *not* using `fread` those constraints are not an issue at all.